# Django: Obj.objects.all().values_list(list)

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a user defined queryset in django. I have tried passing in a list of values to .values_list(). This gives me AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split' Error. Is there a way I can do this?

```
col_list = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']

Obj.objects.all().values_list(col_list)
```

EDIT:

col_list is defined by what the user has selected. The amount of columns or column names is unknown before the user passes it to the view. This is why I used a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As with normal Python, you can use `*` to use a list of strings as arguments:

```
col_list = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']

Obj.objects.all().values_list(*col_list)
```